# Select count from country , city , continent

Tags: mysql

I have a table homes which has country,city,continent fields.

When some searches for a home , if he types for example "rom" I want to return

- Rome (30)
- Romania (120)

How can I do that?

**EDIT**
Use the search form here http://www.holiday-rentals.co.uk/ to see what I mean

**EDIT**
This is what I have tried so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(country),COUNT(city),COUNT(continent) FROM homes WHERE country LIKE '%rom%' OR city LIKE '%rom%' OR continent LIKE '%rom%';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post some sample data, the output you'd like to get, and the query you've tried so far that doesn't work? Pointing people to an external site to figure out what exactly you're asking isn't useful; it means that your question isn't clear, and makes it of no value if the external site is unavailable or goes away in the future. Thanks. :)

Comment: Sorry but I can't describe it well in English... I've updated the question with a query example which doesn't work as I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enhancing Lieven's answer:

```
    SELECT   'city' AS result_type
           , city
           , COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM     homes
    WHERE    city LIKE '%rom%'
    GROUP BY city
UNION ALL
    SELECT   'country' AS result_type
           , country
           , COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM     homes
    WHERE    country LIKE '%rom%'
    GROUP BY country
UNION ALL
    SELECT   'continent' AS result_type
           , continent
           , COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM     homes
    WHERE    continent LIKE '%rom%'
    GROUP BY continent
```